# How to properly comment a partially applied function?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

Given the following function:

```
const sameCharactersAs = a=> b => a.toLowerCase() === b.toLowerCase()
```

or

```
function sameCharactersAs(a){
  return function(b){
      return a.toLowerCase() === b.toLowerCase()
  }
}
```

how would I write the documentation comment above it? How I am currently doing it is:

```
/**
 * checks if the strings have the same characters in the same order
 *
 * @param  {String} a   first string to check
 * @return {Function}   takes second string to check
 * @return {Bool}      
 */
```

but I feel like having two returns isn't correct and not saying what the returned function expects doesn't seem right either. Any rules here or is it just a style preference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I feel like having two returns isn't correct

Indeed not, a function has only one return value and JSDoc will expect only a single `@return`. Just say what it actually does:

```
/**
 * Creates a function to test strings against the given string to see whether
 * they contain the same characters in the same order (case insensitive).
 *
 * @param  {String} a   The string
 * @return {Function}   A function that accepts a second string and returns `true`
 *                      if the second string matches the given string `a` (case
 *                      insensitive) or `false` if it doesn't
 */
```

Comment: I think you can also define a function in a separate tag and then reference it in the `@return`. I don't really know if that's good/wide practice or not (never really had to write completely strict JSDoc) but I _think_ it's possible. When I've had to do something like that, I've just used a bit of Hindley-Milner notation `@return String -> String -> Boolean` which is not proper JSDoc but I've found it describes it well (for the people who'd have to read it, at least).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@typedef` or `@callback` to define the return types of each partially applied function. I don't do this though because it looks funky.

I end up just writing a definition for each function thats worth documenting. Since arrows don't require and curly brace to just immediately return the function, I move the return function to a new line, then add the definition there, between the first function and the returned function, with an extra indent. I think it ends up looking nice in code, and you can use `@alias` to give a name to the anonymous return functions and `@link` to reference functions in the other definitions.

An example (just copied and slightly modified from a project, apologies for all the unnecessary context, and use of flow typing):

```
/**
 * Merge multiple decorators into one decorator.
 *
 * @example
 * const Combined = combineDecorators(Foo, Bar, Baz);
 * Combined(Component) == Foo(Bar(Baz(Component)));
 *
 * @param {...Function} decorators - Decorators that will be combined. Each
 *                                 decorator that is specifed will wrap the
 *                                 proceeding decorator.
 * @returns {Function} Merged decorator function. The result is also a decorator
 *                     and can be passed back into combineDecorators
 */
const combineDecorators = <DP, P, S>(
  ...decorators: Array<DecoratorType<DP, P, S>>
): DecoratorType<DP, P, S> =>
  /**
   * Combined decorator function that is returned by {@link combineDecorators}
   * @alias combinedDecorator
   * @param {Function} WrappedComponent Component to decorate
   * @param {Object} config - configuration that will be passed to each
   *                        decorator
   * @returns {Function} WrappedComponent with decorations
   */
  (
    WrappedComponent: Class<React$Component<DP, P, S>>,
    config: DecoratorConfigType,
  ): Class<React$Component<DP, P, S>> =>
    /**
     * Component that is returned by {@link combinedDecorator}
     * @alias WrappedComponentFn
     * @param {String} foo - foo
     * @returns {Object} bar
     */
     (foo: string) => {
       const bar = decorators.reverse().reduce(
         (WC, decorator) => decorator(WC, config),
         WrappedComponent,
       );
       return {...bar, foo};
     };
```